# Xml comment cref to unknown symbol

Tags: c++-cli, xml-documentation

Trying to go through my project and expand documentation, and have the following situation:

```
//TestClass.h
namespace Test {
    public enum class TypeOne {

        /// <summary>
        /// Description <see cref="Test::TypeTwo">TypeTwo</see>
        /// </summary>
        AAA
    };
    public enum class TypeTwo {
        BBB
    };
}
```

cref produces following error:

> warning C4638: XML document comment applied to 'Test.TypeOne.AAA': reference to unknown symbol 'Test::TypeTwo'.

Is there anyway to get the xml documentation to recognize TypeTwo? I would just put TypeTwo above TypeOne, but TypeTwo also as a cref to TypeOne so I would be back in the same situation.

Am I just being stupid?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to handle this situation like you would regularly for such a circular reference in C++:  Forward declare TypeTwo before TypeOne (but don't define it).

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't forward declare enums in c++/cli.

Comment: For reference, the error is [C2599](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft6cc9ha.aspx)  And the syntax is allowed by C++11, it's called *opaque-enum-declaration* in the grammar.

Comment: Cool. My understanding is this will only be available in Visual Studio 11 and above correct?

Comment: @kylehayward: Much of C++11 will be included in VC++ 2011, but no idea whether this particular rule will be.

Answer (score 0):

I think XML documentation may use C#'s scoping notation (the error message certainly does) regardless of the source file language, so perhaps try `Test.TypeTwo`.

Comment: c++/cli xml comments use c++ scoping notation. Thanks though :)