# Syntax for crossreferencing to a member of another interface in XML comment

Tags: doxygen, c++-cx, xml-documentation

I'm trying to author documentation for some C++/CX interfaces as XML comments. The result will be parsed by Doxygen as well as by VC++'s own `/doc` option.

In the documentation for each interface member, I can use `<see cref="..."/>` syntax to crossreference members of the same interface, as well as to other types that have been forward declared. But what is the proper syntax for referencing a *member* of a different interface?

All of my attempts produce compiler warnings:

> C4638: XML document comment applied to ...: reference to unknown symbol ...

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153455/xml-comment-cref-to-unknown-symbol) and its answers, but you can't forward declare *members* of interface classes, can you? And due to circularity, I cannot always make sure to include the declaration of each referenced interface before the one containing the reference.

If the interface were classes, my understanding is that the XML comments could be put on the *implementations* of the functions rather than their declarations, but for an interface there isn't any implementations of the members that I could move the XML comments to.